# Any free database of English-Spanish words?

Tags: dictionary, translation, vocabulary

I want to make a Vocabulary Trainer and I was thinking about the best way to do it. First I searched some translation APIs to use, to avoid having to build my own dictionary, but I found that most of them are paid and some are free but have limitations.

So, I think the best way is to make my own dictionary, which also allow me to work offline, but I wonder if there is any free database of English-Spanish words to avoid starting from scratch.

Do you know any?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could try http://www.omegawiki.org/ as they claim this:

*The aim of our project is to create a dictionary of all words of all languages, including lexical, terminological and ontological information. Our data is available in a relational database, as a result it is possible to use the data for many purposes.*

Comment: Took my a while to find out where/how the data can be accessed. See http://www.omegawiki.org/Help:Downloading_the_data